# How to update dict with multiple results of for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of arrays:

```
wordList = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
```

I want the following output (keeping always the first value):

```
[{'words': {'word0': 'a', 'word1': 'c', 'word2': 'e'}}]
```

So far I have tried this solution:

```
for i in range(0, len(wordList[0])-1):
jsonList[0].update({"words":{"word"+str(i):wordList[0][i]}}
```

But I receive output just for `word0`:

```
[{'words': {'word0': 'x'}}]
```

What can be changed?

Comment: Presumably you want to do `jsonList['words'].update({"word"+str(i):wordList[0][i]})`, or more simply `jsonList['words']["word"+str(i)] = wordList[0][i]`. You will need to make sure that `jsonList['words']` is an empty dictionary before the loop.

Comment: what is on `wordlist`?

Comment: wordList = [['a', 'b'],
              ['c', 'd'],
              ['e', 'f'],
              ['g', 'h'],
              ['i', 'j'],
              ['k', 'l']]

Comment: @kaya3 the thing is that this jsonList has multiple dicts and i want to update the particular one, e.g. jsonList[0]

Comment: Then change `jsonList` to `jsonList[0]` in my suggestions. But really you need to write a [mcve] and be specific about your requirements.

Comment: and then, you expect `jsonList[0]` to become: `{'words': 'word0': 'a', 'word1': 'c', word2: 'e'` .. etc?

Comment: @PabloFernandez yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your MWE, you are missing an identation which would explain some of your issue :

```py
for i in range(0, len(wordList[0])-1):
    jsonList[0].update({"words":{"word"+str(i):wordList[0][i]}}
```

would be better.

Moreover, you can use the [comprehensive dict declaration](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) (newlines not required)

```
jsonList[0].update({"words":
                       {"word"+str(i):wordList[0][i] for i in range(len(wordList[0]))}
                   }
```

Which would do all of your job. Please note that `range(min,max)` will already go from `min` to `max-1`. And that you don't even need `min` if it is `0` as per [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range).

Then consider using [f-expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) to get :

```py
{f"word{i}":wordList[0][i] for i in range(len(wordList[0]))}
```

Which is as pythonic as it could get (as far as I know)
The finished code would then be :

```py
jsonList[0].update({"words":{f"word{i}":wordList[0][i] for i in range(len(wordList[0]))}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I believe this is the solution you're looking for:

```py
first_values_and_keys = [('word'+str(i), el[0]) for i, el in enumerate(wordList)]
words_dict = {k: v for k, v in first_values_and_keys}
jsonList[0]['words'] = words_dict
```

PS: if you are using python 3.x `'word' + str(i)` can become `f'word{i}'` which is a bit nicer

Comment: anytime! I'll edit the question a bit to make it clearer for other people that might have a similar problem